# Как можно спарсить определение с Википедии? Python

Tags: python, парсер

Каким образом можно спарсить ТОЛЬКО определение с Википедии, а не кусок первого абзаца? И можно ли это сделать?

````
def title(message, wiksum, namestat):
    wikopr=wikipedia.page(namestat).content.split('\n')[0]
    wp=wikipedia.page(namestat)
    title=wp.title    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, title+"\n\n"+wikopr)```
````

Comment: используя библиотеки для парсинга сайтов. Например: BeautifulSoup

Comment: А можете ли дать код? В Гугле не могу найти, там только куски первого абзаца, а не определение...

Comment: вы прикрепите код, который у вас сейчас на данный момент есть.

Comment: Добавил кусок кода в вопрос, как раз в этой функции всё, что связано с Википедией. Но я еще использую библиотеку pytelegrambotapi

Comment: А как вы определяете ТОЛЬКО определение? Что является только определением здесь https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow Или здесь https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Под определением имею в виду только первое предложение. Да, возможно не ясно разъяснено, нужен первый абзац для более подробного объяснения, но мне требуется только первое предложение. Например, с вашей первой ссылки: *Stack Overflow — система вопросов и ответов о программировании[1][2][3], разработанная Джоэлем Спольски и Джеффом Этвудом (англ.) в 2008 году.*

Comment: Просто того, что это система вопросов и ответов о програмировании, уже достаточно

Comment: ну тогда берите первый абзац и все что после первой точки отсекайте через split()

Comment: Проблема в том, что точка может быть не только концом предложения. Например, возьмем кусок предложения *"Смарт-динамик, или умная колонка (англ. smart speaker)"*, то программа выведет только *"Смарт-динамик, или умная колонка (англ." *, а дальше ничего не будет, так как первая точка идет после "англ"

Comment: Наверное, тогда нужно регулярное выражение, которое будет искать всё до точки, которая не находится внутри скобок. Это если конктретно этот случай рассматривать, а так может быть и сокращение какое-нибудь с точкой или аббревиатура

Comment: Тогда, придется брать первый абзац полностью... таких случаев с точкой очень много